# How to create host machine's user on Docker Desktop WSL 2 to mount via `-v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro`?

Tags: docker, docker-desktop

I use Docker Desktop on Windows with WSL 2. I want to run a container with `--user 1000:1000` for example, this user hasn't been created inside the container yet, so I have to mount the host machine's `/etc/passwd` folder to run the container (with `-v /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro`). But where is this `/etc/passwd` on host machine, and how can I add new user to it?

I tried getting to `docker-desktop` distro by command `wsl -d docker-desktop`, but the `/etc/passwd` folder there is not the mounted folder.

Comment: `so I have to mount the host machine's /etc/passwd` - no you don't. The clean way to do it is to create the user inside the container. Edit the `Dockerfile` to create this user and set up required groups, directories and permissions, then run it with `--user 1000`

Comment: But the problem is I don't know which user will be used when running the container. Someone running the container will want to use some arbitrary user they created on their own, not the default user I created in Dockerfile.

Comment: You could  take a build arg from the user to create the the exact ID they'd want to run as later. However that would require every user to build their own image out of your Dockerfile. You could default the build arg to 1000 and ask anyone whose UID is not 1000 to build the image themselves. It's a bit clunky but you wouldn't need the host `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: I understand your idea, but this is a good case, I also used this as an option. But there is another worse case that image users don't want to build from Dockerfile, and I must provide them some commands to create user for mapping to container.

Comment: Yes, the build arg solution is definitely not ideal, but honestly I'm not sure how you could cover every possible use case with every possible uid without requiring a build step.

Comment: Yeah, that's the tough part. Anyway, thank you for your advice.

Comment: For most uses it doesn't matter whether the user actually "exists" in the container or not.  You can use `docker run --user 12345` even if that uid doesn't exist in the container's `/etc/passwd` and nothing bad will happen.  (The only thing I can think of for common use cases is, if you happen to need to `docker exec` a debugging shell, and if you happen to set a more involved prompt, it might say "no such user", but it's just a debugging shell.)

Comment: Contrary to previous discussion here I would not recommend building a host uid into an image; you don't want different users to have to rebuild the image from source just because the host environment is different.

Comment: @DavidMaze yes that's the point that I don't want users to rebuild the image. And, I know I can use not-existing UID, but I need the user's info that comes with `etc/passwd` entry.